# If differencing a non-stationary timeseries makes it stationary. Why dont we difference every series and become rich?

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, econometrics, statistical-power, stationarity

Can every non-stationary time series be converted to a stationary time series by applying differencing, and if yes why not do it on all non-stationary series? Please explain this in plain english without to much math. I have just started my econometrics semester and need to understand this!

Comment: Why do you think that getting a stationary series makes us rich?

Comment: "Can every non-stationary time series be converted to a stationary time series by applying differencing?"  Unfortunately. **No**.

Comment: No.  Only I(1) processes can be made stationary thru differencing.   Even in that case, differencing can sometimes lead to loss of information, due to co-integration.

Comment: I understand that besides having a stationary series you also need significant coefficients to make money.